# MPI user defined type for parts of three different matrices

Tags: c, mpi

I am doing a particle simulation, and need to send some part of three different arrays to other processes. How to use MPI user defined types to do this?

For example, suppose, I have three Matrixes with datatype being double, A, B, and C on Process 1. Now I want to send the first two rows of A, B, and C to Process 2. So how to use MPI user defined type to do this, assuming C type storage for these Matrices? Thank you.

Currently, I am copying the first two rows of these Matrices to a single buffer, and then perform MPI Send. These involves basically the following steps:

```
Copy the first two rows of A, B, and C to a send_buffer on Process 1.
Send the send_buffer from Process 1 to Process 2.
On Process 2, use recv_buffer to receive data from Process 1.
On Process 2, copy data from recv_buffer to A, B, C on Process 2.
```

I hope there is a better way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code showing what you have done so far.

Comment: What does *neighboring process* mean? Where are your matrices currently stored? What ranks are involved overall in the program?

Comment: I have tried to be more clear by adding an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, an MPI data type is defined to communicate a range of rows of a matrix. If there are three matrices then there would be three send/receive. You can compare the following code with your own code to see which one is better.

If you think transferring matrices one by one is not efficient then you might put all matrices inside a struct and  make a MPI data type or consider using `MPI_PACK`.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void make_layout(int row_begin, int row_end, int ncol, MPI_Datatype* mpi_dtype)
{   
    int nblock = 1;
    int block_count = (row_end - row_begin + 1) * ncol;
    MPI_Aint lb, extent;
    MPI_Type_get_extent(MPI_DOUBLE, &lb, &extent);
    MPI_Aint offset = row_begin * ncol * extent;
    MPI_Datatype block_type = MPI_DOUBLE;

    MPI_Type_create_struct(nblock, &block_count, &offset, &block_type, mpi_dtype);
    MPI_Type_commit(mpi_dtype);
}

double** allocate(int nrow, int ncol)
{
    double *data = (double *)malloc(nrow*ncol*sizeof(double));
    double **array= (double **)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double*));
    for (int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[ncol*i]);

    return array;
}

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // make 3x3 matrix.
    int nrow = 3;
    int ncol = 3;
    double** A = allocate(nrow, ncol); 

    // make mpi datatype to send rows [0, 1] excluding row 2.
    // you can send any range of rows i.e. rows [row_begin, row_end].
    int row_begin = 0;
    int row_end = 1; // inclusive.
    MPI_Datatype mpi_dtype;
    make_layout(row_begin, row_end, ncol, &mpi_dtype);

    if (rank == 0)
        MPI_Send(&(A[0][0]), 1, mpi_dtype, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    else
        MPI_Recv(&(A[0][0]), 1, mpi_dtype, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);        

    MPI_Type_free(&mpi_dtype);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Making them a struct is a good idea.  Btw, I tried to vote up this answer, but I don't have 15 reputations, and my vote is not displayed.

Comment: Yes, you need 15 reps to vote up due to probably this [reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41350).